# Android: How do I get the following JSON Object?

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get the latitude and longitudes items from the location in a JSON but I am getting an array out of bounds exception on Android.

Here is the JSON file:

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "21211",
           "short_name" : "21211",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Baltimore",
           "short_name" : "Balt",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Maryland",
           "short_name" : "MD",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Baltimore, MD 21211, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 39.3476939,
              "lng" : -76.619315
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 39.310951,
              "lng" : -76.65690289999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 39.3289463,
           "lng" : -76.63838319999999
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 39.3476939,
              "lng" : -76.619315
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 39.310951,
              "lng" : -76.65690289999999
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJn-Z5WtQEyIkRQx9CtdQF7-I",
     "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

I just need the two attributes:

```
  "location" : {
           "lat" : 39.3289463,
           "lng" : -76.63838319999999
        }
```

I tried doing this but no luck:

```
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jData);
        JSONArray results = jObj.getJSONArray("results");
        JSONObject geometry = results.getJSONObject(2); //ERROR RIGHT HERE!
        JSONObject  location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
        Double latitude = location.getDouble("lat");
        Double longitude = location.getDouble("lng");
```

Comment: Why not getting it as JSONObject geometry = results.getJSONObject("geometry");

Comment: It looks like `"results"` is an array of dictionaries (an array of one dictionary, in your example).

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin because results is an array and getJSONObject() takes only an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get your geomettry as you did,since there is no object at with the index 2 in your json object.
I think you have not formatted well your json responce.
Copy past your responce in this [web site](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and you ll understand.

and here is some code:

```
JSONObject tmp = results.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject geometery = tmp.getJSONObject ("geometery");
```

Comment: Nope the response seems to be formatted well:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=21211&sensor=true

Comment: see the code I just posted, u ll understand what I mean.

Comment: that does not work. the second line asks for a string not an int.

Comment: changing the 2 to geometry solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @dikshant why have u unvalidate my answer didn't it solve your problem?

Comment: Oops I didn't mean to.

Answer (score 2):

You should get `JSONObject geometry = results.getJSONObject(0);` because there is only one object in the array. However, if I were you, I'd create an `ArrayList` and use `for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)` to get every object in case of coming more than one object, doing something like:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jData);
JSONArray results = jObj.getJSONArray("results");

ArrayList<LocationObject> _locationList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++){

    JSONObject geometry = results.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry");

    JSONObject  location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");

    LocationObject _locationObject = new LocationObject();

    _locationObject.setLat(location.getDouble("lat"));
    _locationObject.setLng(location.getDouble("lng"));

    _locationObject.add(_locationObject);

}
```